# A pattern for change notification on nested properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind to a property of a property of my ViewModel. The nested object is not known at compile time so I cannot just set the binding path to one of its properties directly. Instead, I bind to the object as a whole and a value converter seeks out the property (or properties) of interest using reflection.

The binding and value converter work fine initially, but the value converter is not called if the values of the nested properties are altered (it is if the reference to this object is changed in the VM). Both VM and nested class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Here is a simplified example in which if the value of `Name` is initially set to "Bond" the secret is revealed, but never is if the combo box value is changed to "Bond" while the program is running:

**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="vm" />
    <local:NameToVisConverter x:Key="NameToVis" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding MyPoco.Name}">
        <sys:String>Smith</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Jones</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Bond</sys:String>
    </ComboBox>

    <Label Visibility="{Binding MyPoco, Converter={StaticResource NameToVis}}">
        Secret!
    </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

**ViewModel & nested class:**

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public Poco MyPoco
    {
        get { return _MyPoco; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _MyPoco, value); }
    }
    private Poco _MyPoco = new Poco();
}

public class Poco : BindableBase
{
    public String Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Name, value); }
    }
    private String _Name;

}
```

**Note:** `BindableBase` and its `SetProperty()` are provided by Prism and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**Value conversion methodfrom `NameToVisConverter`:**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return (value as Poco).Name == "Bond"
        ? Visibility.Visible
        : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

I naively expected that the binding would be alerted if a property of an `INotifyPropertyChanged` class is changed if the binding is on the object itself rather than on one of the object's properties. Obviously it isn't... is there a good pattern (or, hopefully, a simple workaround) for dealing with this situation?

Comment: Wait, are you having the parent viewmodel raise `PropertyChanged("MyPoco")`, whenever one of `MyPoco`'s properties changes? I would expect that to work.

Comment: An alternative might be to write a MarkupExtension which creates a new binding dynamically when `MyPoco` changes value. But that sounds like it might be something of an adventure. The above method should work.

Comment: @EdPlunkett No. That sounds lke it would work (unless there's a check elsewhere, such as the `PropertyChangedEventManager`, which will notice that the reference actually hasn't changed), but it feels wrong to hijack an event with a particular meaning and force another upon it. Perhaps I'm being too picky! [Incidentally, I meant "No" as in, "I haven't done that", not "No" as in "I wouldn't consider that"!]

Comment: I was actually wondering about forcing a binding update (`BindingExpression.UpdateTarget()`) when the Poco INPC event fires.

Comment: To me it seems like a very minor abuse of the mechanism. Imagine if `Poco` were immutable, like `String`. To change a property on it, you'd have to create a new one with the new property value, and your parent vm would call `OnPropertyChanged("MyPoco")`. If you have a string property `Foo` and the XAML binds to `Foo.Length`, it's the same case.

Comment: You could do that `UpdateTarget()` thing, but then you're adding a bunch of C# code just to avoid what's at worst a very mild deviation from orthodoxy. If there were a straightforward clean 100% pure XAML way to avoid it, I'd say yes, absolutely -- but in a choice among evils, what's the simplest and most maintainable evil?

Comment: You've convinced me. I've implemented (so quick, you're right) and it works fine. Want to suggest it in an answer?

Comment: This should work <Label DataContext="{Binding Binding MyPoco}" Visibility="{Binding , Converter={StaticResource NameToVis}}"> so when you change the entire datacontext, anything inside should be updated, and then the visibility is just binding without telling to what (which means to the datacontext which is MyPoco).

Comment: @BobSammers Done, thanks

Comment: @adminSoftDK You're right that'd work, but you're still raising `PropertyChanged("MyPoco")`, so I don't see what you'd gain. Also you'd lose the ability to bind anything else on the `Label` to properties of the parent viewmodel.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah, the property change is still required, but I don't see how can you lose any ability to bind to anything else? if you need something outside of the MyPoco, you can just use relative source binding.

Comment: @adminSoftDK That's true. If you add that problem, you can can work around it. But why would you add that problem?

Comment: @adminSoftDK That's quite a neat XAML-only solution (assuming it works - it's not clear to me that PropertyChanged events on the `DataContext` properties will necessarily be fed through to an empty binding; that feels similar to the problem I had to start with, but you may be right). In my actual use case, I can't easily alter the `DataContext` (the binding in question is on a panel with further content), so this would probably complicate matters more than simplify. I think that makes it less flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd just have the parent VM raise `PropertyChanged("MyPoco")` when any of `MyPoco`'s properties changes (or should be presumed to have changed, or whatever the situation is). This will cause the binding to update the target, and your converter's `Convert` will be called.

Alternatives would involve C# code you'd have to write and debug and maintain, and this is a perfectly normal way to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` in cases where the XAML binds to a property of a property value object that's immutable, or doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For example, I've bound `StringProperty.Length` a few times, or `NullableProperty.HasValue`.